# How to update a supervision tree on a live code upgrade?

Tags: erlang, elixir, erlang-otp

An issue I’ve run into with live code upgrades is when there’s a change to a supervision tree’s structure. A supervisor which was supervising a process of type `MyApp.Worker1` and a process of type `MyApp.Worker2` now needs to also supervise a 3rd  process of type `MyApp.Worker3`.

Updating `MySupervisor.init/1` will start up the supervisor correctly, but does not change the current supervisor's structure assuming the supervisor never crashes.

Obviously, I can restart the node, but that defeats the purpose of a live code upgrade. I can `my_app remote_console` in and manually do `Supervisor.start_child/2` if I have the supervisor registered, but manual intervention is not feasible with a wide deployment across lots of nodes.

What are the best practices for updating a supervision tree (both additions and removals) during a live code upgrade? Ideally, this would take into account any differences between Erlang and Elixir modules (a.k.a. be cross-language compatible)

Comment: This might be useful: http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/appup_cookbook.html#sup.

Comment: `rtfm` is always a valid answer. Put it in an answer, and I'll accept it :)

Comment: That was really just meant as pointer if you wanted to figure it out. Let's see if anyone gives a simpler explanation, especially in the context of Elixir and exrm.